# Stream video/audio from an endpoint protected by OAuth2, Android?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

So I have to access a media file which is on the server. I have to add access token to header so I can access the file. My goal is to play the media. The usual code is like this:

```
//for audio
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();

//for video
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
videoView.start();
```

Now consider that the `url` that I'm calling needs an `OAuth2` authentication, which literally means adding an `access-token` to the header of the request. Is this possible by any means in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [setDataSource override](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)) to include custom headers, so I believe this will work:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken):
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, url, headers);
```